# Adding object to different view and immediately follow finger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there any way to add an object from one view to another and have the object immediately follow the user's finger.  A `UIImageView` exists within a `UIScrollView`.  You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to remove it from the `UIScrollView` add it to the overall view.

I would like to have the imageview then follow the touch on the main view.  The `UIImageView` has a `UIPanGesture` to control movement.  The problem is that between the longpress and the pan you have to raise the finger and re-tap the screen.  Is there any way to add the object to the main view and have it already following the user's finger without having to raise their finger?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect moving of a finger after long press by catching current state of UILongPressGestureRecognizer. For example:

Recognizer declaration:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* Long = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
```

Method implementation:

```
-(void)longPressDetected:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)Long{

    switch ([Long state]) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:

            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:

            NSLog(@"Got it!")l // Long press is successfully recognized
            break;


        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:


            NSLog(@"Wow! Its moving!"); // finger position has changed

            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:


        default:
            break;
    }
}
```